# Jquery doesn't perform a simple condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Everything from the server works perfectly well, but just this simple conditional statement is not working for some reason.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logsubmit").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val()
        var password = $("#pwd").val()

        $.post("functions/logincheck.php", {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }, function(result) {
            if (result == "success") {
                window.location = "/";
            } else {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Even if the `result == success` the `else` statement is being executed for some reason.

The PHP script:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../connect.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$lgchk = $con->prepare("select uid, pass from userlogin where uname = :uname");
$lgchk->bindParam(':uname', $username);
$lgchk->execute();

if ($lgchk->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $lgchk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $pass = htmlentities($row['pass']);
        $id   = htmlentities($row['uid']);
    }
    if ($password == $pass) {
        $_SESSION["myid"] = $id;
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Password";
    }
} else {
    echo "Account Doesnt Exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `result` *is* success?

Comment: Then it seems obvious that `result` is not equal to `success`. You need to debug why that is. Are you sure it's not `'   result'`? Try `result.trim() == 'success'`. If that works I'd strongly suggest you change your PHP to return JSON to both avoid whitespace errors, and also use a boolean value properly, instead of an ugly string comparison.

Comment: I can guarantee You that the result is success because in the else alert i am getting an alert that says "success".

Comment: Don't use `alert()` to debug *anything*. It coerces types. Use `console.log()`. Did you try using `trim()` as I suggested?

Comment: i did try trim and it doesnt help. I remember using a similar function in a previous case and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: why are you not stringifying your data?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is not a json object. it is a php echo. just see my php script that i have added in my question which returns the result.

Comment: @reevkandari . Do a typeof(result), check what you get.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it says its a string

Comment: @Shiladitya it says its a string

Comment: @reevkandari . Can you check the length? `console.log(result.length);`

Comment: @Shiladitya it says 8

Comment: @reevkandari. But 'success' is 7 character work. That means some space is attached to it. Try `var new result = result.trim();`

Comment: @Shiladitya The OP already tried that apparently.

Comment: @Shiladitya it worked

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you were right.

Comment: @reevkandari you could have saved yourself a lot of time if you'd done what I suggested

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i had tried it but since it outputted the same string , i didnt try putting it through the confitional loop, but later when shiladitya suggested to compare the lengths it worked . I am still not convinced how the extra space made its way in the data though.

Comment: It's because you're returning plain text from the PHP instead of a formatted data structure, like JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logsubmit").click(function() {
    var username = $("#username").val()
    var password = $("#pwd").val()

    $.post("functions/logincheck.php", {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }, function(result) {
      var r = result.trim();
        if (r == "success") {
            window.location = "/";
        } else {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Use `trim` method & then assign it to some other variable.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It worked like a charm Thanks for Your help.... but i am still clueless as to why did it happen.. since i didn't return any extra space from the php..